# Trying to attach js console for my js editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I have created the Javascript editor using CodeMirror and I'm trying to attach the `console.log` to the editor so all `console.log` calls should display in `console.log`

```js
function loadCSS() {
    var $head = $("#preview").contents().find("head");                
    $head.html("<style>" + editor.getValue() + "</style>");
}; 
function loadJS() {
    var scriptTag = "<script>"+editorJS.getValue()+"<";
    scriptTag +=  "/script>";
    
    var previewFrame2 = document.getElementById('preview');
    var preview2 =  previewFrame2.contentDocument ||  previewFrame2.contentWindow.document;
    preview2.open();
    preview2.write(editor2.getValue()+scriptTag);
    preview2.close();
    
    loadCSS();

};
var delayJS;
var editorJS = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('codeJS'), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  styleActiveLine: true,
  matchBrackets: true,
  mode: 'javascript'
});

editorJS.on("change", function() {
  clearTimeout(delayJS);
  delayJS = setTimeout(updatePreviewJS, 300);
});

function updatePreviewJS() {
  loadJS();
}
setTimeout(updatePreviewJS, 300);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.59.3/codemirror.min.js" integrity="sha512-JGXg57jFqbsyKRnyYM4AUoa/So9B6d8Mb93a0d/y3LiWjztbB5RDGxMiBCMNpOhh1/8fAs0hxgWSiZaTOoTY/Q==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.59.3/codemirror.min.css" integrity="sha512-MWdvo/Qqcf4pY1ecQUB1uBn0qLp19U/qJ1Rpp2BDZeuBA7YsFEwkvqR/+aG4BroPiAYDunKJ6X8R/Pmdt3p7oA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<textarea id="codeJS" class="code js-code-to-run" name="codeJS" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Enter code here ..." style="width: 810px; height: 200px">
  document.getElementById('skillraryText').style.color = 'red';
  console.log("Hello World");
</textarea>
```

Comment: The part of the logic which handles the output of the code which is entered is missing from the question. Please edit to include the content of `loadJS`.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan please find my changes